# Java remainder calculations

Tags: java

Trying to take the remainder of two values and setting it equal to the variable `intRem` which I will call later on in my program. I am getting the error "bad operand types for binary operator '%' ". Here is my code:

```
// Import a buffered reader to read user input below
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputValues1;

// User enters 4 integer values here
System.out.println("Enter 4 integer values");
inputValues1 = input.readLine();
String[] intValues = inputValues1.split("\\s+");

int intRem = ((intValues[0] + intValues[2]) % (intValues[1] + intValues[3])); 

System.out.println(intRem);
```

How can I solve this to print out the variable `intRem` at the end? I am getting the error with the remainder sign somehow....

Comment: [it does work](http://ideone.com/4FDGL6). can you put some more code?

Comment: Your error probably doesn't come from this line of code.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal there is the coding for the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure all your `intValues` array elements are `int`and you did not accidentally cast/parse them to other data types like `String` before performing the `%` calculation.

Just as I suspected. All your intValues are String. You need to ensure those are int before doing your calculations.

**Do this:**

```
int intRem = ((Integer.parseInt(intValues[0]) + Integer.parseInt(intValues[2])) % (Integer.parseInt(intValues[1]) + Integer.parseInt(intValues[3])));
```

Above codes will convert all your `String` variables to `int`.

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart You are welcome. Everyone makes mistakes. That's  fine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine,check & run the code below-

```
//package com.nawab.standalone;

public class Main
{
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int intValues[]=new int[]{0,1,2,3};

    int intRem = ((intValues[0] + intValues[2]) % (intValues[1] + intValues[3])); 
    System.out.println("hi:"+intRem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

[image]

because you are using

```
String[] intValues
```

instead it is supposed to be

```
int[] intValues
```

or you should parse every element of array to `int` as `Integer.parseInt(intValues[0])`.

```
int intRem = ((Integer.parseInt(intValues[0]) + 
               Integer.parseInt(intValues[2])) % 
              (Integer.parseInt(intValues[1]) + 
               Integer.parseInt(intValues[3])));
```

Comment: This won't work. You look at his codes. He is using string.split() method, that is why he is using String array.

Comment: I'm suggesting him not to use  `String[]`. he needs to store it in `int[]` or he will need to parse them every time he use them.